# How to aggregate jsonb object?

Tags: postgresql

I have `jsonb` field in table with values like that:

```
{
"1":[{"start":64800,"finish":68400},{"start":61200,"finish":64800},{"start":75600,"finish":79200},{"start":79200,"finish":82800}],
"2":[{"start":68400,"finish":72000},{"start":72000,"finish":75600},{"start":75600,"finish":79200},{"start":79200,"finish":82800}],
"3":[{"start":46800,"finish":50400},{"start":50400,"finish":54000}],
"4":[{"start":50400,"finish":54000}],
"5":[{"start":79200,"finish":82800},{"start":82800,"finish":0},{"start":0,"finish":3600}],
"6":[{"start":68400,"finish":72000},{"start":72000,"finish":75600},{"start":79200,"finish":82800}]
}
```

0...6 - day of week, it's array of working time.

So I need to aggregate working time by days of week. For example, one row has

`"5":[{"start":79200,"finish":82800},{"start":82800,"finish":0},{"start":0,"finish":3600}]`

another row has

`"5":[{"start":75600,"finish":79200}]`

and I want to get

`"5":[{"start":75600,"finish":79200},{"start":79200,"finish":82800},{"start":82800,"finish":0},{"start":0,"finish":3600}]`

Comment: This would be soooo simple with a properly normalized data model

Comment: The first data set is only one row with all those values? Or each line is a row in the database?

Comment: What is the Postgresql version?

Comment: I use `postgresql 9.6`, one row corresponds to one user and field contains working time for each day of week.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this report to be run manually & irregularly, you can do this [within PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) itself. But if performance matters to you, you should normalize your schema (f.ex. if your `jsonb` column's structure is that simple, there is literally no need to use JSON at all: you don't have any unstructured data).

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(dow, working_times_agg)
FROM   (SELECT     dow, jsonb_agg(working_time) working_times_agg
        FROM       table t,
                   jsonb_each(t.jsonb_column) o(dow, working_times),
                   jsonb_array_elements(working_times) working_time
        GROUP BY   dow) working_times_agg_by_dow
```